# Difference between column- and row vector matrix multiplication (vector transform)

Tags: mathematics, directxmath

Let's say we have a 4-by-4 matrix \$A\$ which represents some transformation.

We can use this matrix to transform a vector in two ways.

- \$Ax\$ by assuming \$x\$ is a 4-by-1 column vector.
- \$xA\$ by assuming \$x\$ is a 1-by-4 row vector.

Up until yesterday, I have not seen this \$xA\$ variant and I thought it was unnecessary. Then I came across [this DirectX code from Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath/blob/d98156cdb7a0ab742d590487c6a436bd7cf2d292/Inc/DirectXCollision.inl#L4248).

This function takes *just* the projection matrix, computes the inverse projection matrix and then does this \$xA\$ variant (not \$Ax\$) to transform (or unproject) a bunch of coordinates.

At first, I wasn't looking and did \$Ax\$ which came out nonsensical and now I'm trying to understand why.

I've noticed that \$Ax = xA^T\$ but when I look at the way the matrix multiplication is carried out. The components that make up the result are very different depending on whether I use \$Ax\$ or \$xA\$ (as it should be, matrix multiplication is not commutative).

The analytic solution for \$Ax\$ (3-by-3 matrix and row vector)

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
ax + dy + gz \\
bx + ey + hz \\
cx + fy + iz
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The analytic solution for \$xA\$ (3-by-3 matrix and column vector)

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
ax+by+cz \\
dx+ey+fz \\
gx+hy+iz
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I use Mathematica to test these things. On a hunch I tried the analyitic solution for \$xA\$ with the elements of \$A\$ transposed manually and of course, I get:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & d & g \\
b & e & h \\
c & f & i
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
ax+by+cz \\
dx+ey+fz \\
gx+hy+iz
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which is equivalent to \$Ax\$ except we now have a column vector not a row vector. I'm assuming all of this is purely conventional (and depends on whether I'm assuming row- or column-major matrix layout). It looks like I might have answered the question my self but if I'm wrong about anything here please correct me.

Comment: As you said, it is purely conventional. Some people prefer rows, other columns, it also depends on which library you use, but it does not change anything

Comment: @realUser404 thanks. I think this has been like the most annoying thing to get to grips with when doing 3D math. Not knowing (or disregarding) the conventions has sent me tripping on more than one occasion.

Comment: I can only recommend the excellent "Game Engine Architecture" by Jason Gregory, it explains very well all you need to know, including 3D Math

Comment: @realUser404 Funny you would say that because I have the book right here. I will review the chapters on the 3D math straight away.

Comment: Algebraically-wise, the difference is definitely purely conventional. But engineering-wise, there is a reason for preferring column-major over the row-major order. This is because there are hardware-accelerated operations that take advantage of the former vs the latter, one example being matrix multiplication with SSE instructions. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499971/efficient-4x4-matrix-multiplication-c-vs-assembly.

Comment: Yes, almost all linear algebra uses the row major convention since matrices are operators and operators are usually applied in a left-to-right fashion; this is because operators, just like functions, act on certain quantities. It feels natural to say "apply this operator to that object" not vice-versa "on this object apply that operator". Both sentences are correct in both natural and mathematical language. But in the mathematical language, one has to switch the major axis (column or row) for both operand and operator (i.e. vector and matrix) and then switch their order of appearance.

Comment: @teodron I'm familiar with some of the things to talk about. I looked over the DOOM 3 BFG source code and noticed that all matrices are in row-major order except the 3-by-3 matrices. Clearly, 3-by-3 matrices are by far the most commonly used matrix but is strikes me as odd that they would go with two sets of memory layout as it is inconsistent.

Comment: @teodron with regards to performance though, I will say this. Having a faster matrix multiplication function is great but if you have many objects that need to update, to truly leverage SSE/SIMD you will have to implement a function that forgoes any matrix multiplication function to ensure that you are always fetching and never stall the CPU. Care must be taken to arrange the memory of all the objects that need to update not just single matrix to single matrix multiplication. This is something that can be hard to do in hindsight.

Comment: Row-major vs column-major is the one of main differences between OpenGL and DirectX. It seems OpenGL uses column-major, while DirectX uses row-major. It's pure conventional, but it starts to matter in what order to perform matrix vs vector multiplication in shader.
In GLSL shader if use OpenGL based math library you would use "A*x" convention, but if you use DirectX based math library for your OpenGL app, you would need to use "x*A convention". 

Also this makes difference in what order you need to multiply your matrices.

Comment: In OpenGL based math libraries it's mat4.mult(ProjectionMatrix, mat4.mult(ViewMatrix ,ModelMatrix)), while in DirectX based math libraries it's mat4.mult(mat4.mult(ModelMatrix,ViewMatrix),ProjectionMatrix)

Comment: @DmitryTolmachov thanks for pointing that out. I think it makes sense. I will have to review my math library thoroughly. I think it's right but I keep messing up the conventions accidentally.

Comment: @DmitryTolmachov I think the issue is simply that I have accidentally been doing `Ax` when I should have been doing `xA`. When I did my matrix transform function I accidentally implemented it as `Ax` but it should have been `xA`.

Comment: @realUser404 p. 152 section 4.3.2.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren I have the 2nd edition of the book, so it might not be the same exactly, but it was indeed the section 4.3.2 I was refering to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer I was looking for was laid out in **@DmitryTolmachov**'s comment.

> Row-major vs column-major is the one of main differences between
>   OpenGL and DirectX. It seems OpenGL uses column-major, while DirectX
>   uses row-major. It's pure conventional, but it starts to matter in
>   what order to perform matrix vs vector multiplication in shader. In
>   GLSL shader if use OpenGL based math library you would use "Ax"
>   convention, but if you use DirectX based math library for your OpenGL
>   app, you would need to use "xA convention". Also this makes difference
>   in what order you need to multiply your matrices.

We can turn row-major into column-major by transposing the matrix. In my particular case I have been using row-major for my 4-by-4 matrix. I then transpose these matrices when I send them to OpenGL (I use OpenGL).

Since I'm using a row-major convention for my matrix math library, transforming a vector must be implemented as `xA`. If I use a column-major convention I implement vector transform as `Ax`.

It doesn't matter which you use but you cannot mix them (that would be undefined behavior) and the end result must be compatible (with regards to their respective shader language) with the 3D API we're using, be it DirectX or OpenGL or something else.

Comment: it is worth noting that A: HLSL itself is in column-major and B: D3D (atleast D3D11) lets you compile shaders with 
`D3DCOMPILE_PACK_MATRIX_COLUMN_MAJOR`. Which omits the transposing on the CPU (with a minimal gpu cost)